# Grand total By Expression or MDX - SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I want to get the grand total of `[Measures].[Total Sales With Tax]`. From there I can work on getting ratios. The query I have is this.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ 
     [Measures].[Total Sales With Tax], 
     [Measures].[Sales Amount With Tax] 
} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY 
{ 
     ([Date].[Day Number].[Day Number].ALLMEMBERS )
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [DSV Airline Management System DW]
```

I tried other online example with the `sum` command. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use axis function, try the query below

```
with member [Measures].[SumTotal Sales With Tax]
as
sum(Axis(1),[Measures].[Total Sales With Tax])

SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ 
     [Measures].[Total Sales With Tax], 
     [Measures].[Sales Amount With Tax],
     [Measures].[SumTotal Sales With Tax] 
} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY 
{ 
     ([Date].[Day Number].[Day Number].ALLMEMBERS )
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM [DSV Airline Management System DW]
```